# JavaScript submit button onclick redirect not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

Why this JavaScript code is not redirecting to the URL ? What is wrong with this code?

```
function submitform() {
    var hiddenFieldValue = document.getElementById('course').value;
    alert("inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue);
    window.location.href= "inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue); 
    return false;
}
```

HTML code

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST">
        <p>
            Course Name <label>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
            <!--input type="button" value="Get Value" /-->
            <input type="text" name="course_val" id="course_val" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="submitform()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Iam not sure but use a full URL like http://inidonesia.org/

Comment: Yes have done @Webice.. But, it still no luck

Comment: and there is an extra `)` in the window.location.href line.

Answer (score 2):

As you are relying on button click, what is the need of the form??
As you put that in <form &rt; it is not working. remove form, it will work

```
        <p>
        Course Name <label>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="course" id="course" />
        <!--input type="button" value="Get Value" /-->
        <input type="text" name="course_val" id="course_val" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="submitform()"/>
```

Remove form.

Answer (score 1):

You need `http://` on the URL. You code updated:

```
function submitform(){
    var hiddenFieldValue = document.getElementById('course').value;
    alert("inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue);
    window.location.href= "http://inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue); 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use only

```
window.location = url;
```

or

```
window.location.replace = url;
```

instead off

```
window.location.href
```

cause that simulates a link

here is the discussion

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Yes i have change to window.location.replace = url; and add 'http://'.. but it still not redirect to url.. @Webice

Answer (score 0):

**you are doing this :**

```
 window.location.href= "inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue);
```

change it to this :

```
 window.location.href= "inindonesia.org/marketplace/tags/"+hiddenFieldValue;
```

**NOTE THE ')' that i deleted at the end of the line.**